# How to display category list with category featured image

Tags: plugins, categories

I am using Category Featured Image Plugin :
https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-featured-image/
which sets a featured image for post by a category.

The reason behind using this plugin is, it adds category images as featured images for post as I don't use any separate feature images for post.

Now, I want to display all WordPress categories on a page, using WP Category widget. How can I retrieve that featured image, bcos WordPress category only provides list of all categories

Comment: You should ask plugin questions to the plugin authors - they should be able to assist and show you documentation.

Comment: Yes, but as its a free plugin so the developer wouldn't offer this much customization. What i thought is as the plugin is already adding featured image upload option for category, so there might be some way to retrieve it